# Why when paste variant value I retreiver number intead text?

Tags: excel, vba, variant

I think is simple, but I'll crazy.
this image show exactly my problem.
I've on table, 2 columns with texts, I add table values into a variant, when I "paste" the values i retreive one column with numbers and one with texts?!
This is my simple code to explain my program:

```
Sub test()
Dim testVal, testRng As Range

Set testRng = Range("A1:B10")
testVal = testRng.Value

With testRng.Offset(, 2)
.Value = testVal
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

How I can resolve this problem and retreive Number or Text, as a origin value

Comment: You have to implement a way to copy the formatting like `Range("A1:B10").Copy Range("A1:B10").Offset(, 2)` to get desired results. You are only copying values with the current code and not formatting.

Comment: ...or apply the same formatting of column A to column C :-)

Comment: The value of the cell is `0601100001`. But leading zeros means nothing so Excel deletes them, and returns a number. So you must copy as text, or lead each single cell with a single quote like `'` to force Excel to read data as text. Or format destiny cells as text before pasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like when you type in a value, Excel will examine it and infer the type that it thinks you want. Sometimes you need to *specify* the format in order to force Excel to format the value as text:

```
With testRng.Offset(, 2)
  .NumberFormat = "@"
  .Value = testVal
End With
```

Or use Excel's built-in copy/paste that can include formats:

```
Dim testVal, testRng As Range

Set testRng = Range("A1:B10")
testRng.Copy

With testRng.Offset(, 2)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thumbs up!

Comment: This assumes that cells are always formatted as text (which is apparently the case). What if the formatting is not text? the code may give undesired result. I see that it is addressed per the edit.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I added an option that uses the native copy/paste that includes formats.